# How to deal with change in default of lubridate's ymd

Tags: r, lubridate

In `ymd` from lubridate, the default value of `tz` was `UTC`.  I don't know exactly when the change was made but I know that in 1.5 the default was UTC but in 1.5.8 the default is now `NULL`.

This changes the output of `ymd` from `POSIXct` objects to `Date` objects which breaks a lot of my code where I rely on having a `POSIXct` object but now have a `Date`.  Is there a convenient way to make this backwards compatible or do I need to add the `tz='UTC'` to all of my old code that relied on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a wrapper to replace `ymd` with `ymd_hms` for which the default is still `tz = "UTC"`

```
library(lubridate)
ymd2 = function(x){
    ymd_hms(paste(x, "00:00:00"))
}

ymd2("2017/3/4")
#[1] "2017-03-04 UTC"

class(ymd2("2017/3/4"))
#[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Comment: yeah I thought about making a wrapper like `ymd2<-function(x) ymd(x, tz='UTC')` but am hoping for something that doesn't involve doing this in every piece of code that uses `ymd`.

Comment: Well you could name the wrapper `ymd` and then call `lubridate::ymd` with the `tz` argument inside to avoid name clashes... Then you wouldn't have to replace all your `ymd` calls in existing code, just load the function. Otherwise you might be stuck using an older version of `lubridate`. The `packrat` package might be useful in that case.

Comment: You could also post a feature request to get a default tz option in `options`: https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues. I doubt you're the only one having this version compatibility issue.